# The "OK" command button in VBA Userform fails to be defaulted

Tags: excel, vba

My vba userform has two command buttons: CancelButton and OkButton. The property settings are shown in the pictures

**Cancel Button**

[image: fig: cancel property]

**Ok Button**

[image: fig: OkButton]

The **"OK"** button should have been made default, but the executed user interface shows **"Cancel"** button is by default

[image: fig:the executed userform]

Could anyone work out the reason why the **"OK"** key is not made default? Should not the defaulted button with **"OK"** being enclosed by dashed lines? Like,

[image: expected result]

Comment: It looks like your Cancel button is first in the tab order. That is nothing to do with the `Cancel` or `Default` properties.

Comment: its true. tabIndex for Cancel is 0 and for OK is 1. Just need to invert

Comment: Thank @Luis Curado. It works now.

Comment: @Rory Thanks, you have worked it out.